# When endpoints aren't local extremes

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

I was trying to think of examples of functions $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ that are continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ where the endpoints $(a,f(a))$ or $(b,f(b))$ are not local extremes. I know for example that the topologist's sine curve $ f(x) = \begin{cases} xsin(\frac{1}{x}) ,  0 < x \leq 1 \\
      0 ,  x=0 \end{cases}$.

is an example where the endpoint $(0,0)$ isn't a local extreme, but $f$ isn't continuous there.

Are there any examples?

My guess is no since a continuous function on compact set attains its max and min, so $f$ attains max and min on $[a,\frac{b-a}{2}]$, $[a,\frac{b-a}{4}]$,... so I would think eventually $a$ would be a max or min and similarly for $b$, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is continuous at $0$  but not differentiable there.

That can be fixed. Smooth it out a bit or a lot. For example let  $f(x)=x^{10}\sin(1/x)$ when $x\ne 0$, and let $f(0)=0$.

We can even make it infinitely differentiable by using $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}\sin(1/x)$ when $x\ne 0$, and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: So you're saying that we can make $f$ smooth on $[0,1]$ **and** $(0,0)$ isn't a local max/min, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: You are welcome. The function $e^{-1/x^2}$ is useful in producing "bump" functions, please see Wikipedia.